# Using question mark within query in golang

Tags: mysql, go

I'm creating a query to select rows with a given URL.

I'm using this code to create the query and retrieve the data

```
  pages_query := `
            SELECT id
            FROM   pages
            WHERE  url = 'my.url.com?param=23/'`
  stmt, err := datastore.DB.Prepare(pages_query)
  rows, err := stmt.Query()
```

But it does not retrieve any data, though there are records matching that query in the database.

I believe that is because the stmt.Query() replaces the '?' with none, but I haven't been able to scape it.

How could I scape that question mark?

Comment: To ask the obvious, have tried putting a backslash before the `?` ?

Comment: I tried backslash before the ? (sigle and double backslash) and none of them worked.

In the database the table pages has some rows with the value  'my.url.com?param=23/' in  the column url

Comment: Do you have problems querying those without a question mark?

Comment: Guess - make the url value a parameter in the prepared statement and then pass the url as a parameter in `Query()`

Comment: `stmt.Query()` really should not replace any `'?'` that is inside an SQL string literal, that is within the single-quotes. In SQL, parameter placeholders are treated as a literal ? character if they are part of an SQL string literal. I think you are mistaken, and the content in your database is simply not matching the pattern you're searching for.

Comment: There were blank spaces in the database, that's why it didn't retrieve any row.